# WebDriver logging to print sendKeys data

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been using Firefox logging as following -

```
((FirefoxDriver) webDriver).setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
```

This gets me all browser operation logged for ex -

```
INFORMATION: Executed: [057a3eaa-2878-454b-bd52-89f7053e32cc, findElement {using=xpath, value=//input[contains(@id,'_j_username')]}]
```

But sendKeys operation logs cryptic information with id and CharSequence object -

```
INFORMATION: Executing: sendKeysToElement [057a3eaa-2878-454b-bd52-89f7053e32cc, sendKeysToElement {id={17d0dee8-81e5-a741-975d-c7be4612f2ce}, value=[Ljava.lang.CharSequence;@1ce858f9}]
```

More useful information would be the element locator and test data being sent to browser. How do I get precisely this information from browser logging?

I am on selenium 2.53.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logging information containing executing, executed, exception etc are created by the `execute()` method in the `RemoteWebDriver` class. The executing line is before the command is fired and executed is after the response is received. The `execute()` method takes the **command as a string** and **map as a parameter** which contains the details required by the command to execute.

So in case of a `findElement()` the map will contain the locator strategy(using in log info) such as id,css etc and the value(value in log info) to use. In case of `sendKeys()` only the id (internal id of the WebElement) and the value(data to input) is sent as parameter. And that is all you see in the logging info.

Now the `RemoteWebElement` stores the locator details in the **foundBy String private variable** - contains the locator strategy and the value. Also the **toString() method** of the `RemoteWebElement` prints out this variable contents. You will need to include any of the two to the parameters map in the `RemoteWebElement` class (in this case `sendKeys` method) that is sent to the `execute()` method and you should get the details if I am correct.

Comment: About 
< You will need to include any of the two to the parameters map in the RemoteWebElement class. >
I think I read something wrong since `sendKeys` method already take `string parameter` to be keyed in to field. And when I use `toString` method from `RemoteWebElement ` then it gets me element locator (one problem solved) but the actual content which is to be typed in input box is yet missing.

Comment: The content to be sent is present in the parameters map with the key 'value' but it contains a CharSequence array, so the toString() method gives the object address. You could include another parameter in this map in the sendKeys() method with a string representation of the 'value'. The logger will output the actual value now.

Comment: seems current version of selenium indeed has charSequence argument in `beforeChangeValueOf` API -

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html#beforeChangeValueOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver-java.lang.CharSequence:A-

I just had to convert charSequence to String and got the value printed :)